# Slice list of lists at regular interval then merge

Tags: python

How would you "columnize" a list of lists at every `x`th index?

I was thinking of doing this by taking the starting list, then creating two new lists, merging them, then adding the remainder not divisible by `x`.

For example with an interval of 2:

```
start = [
    [1, 'one'],
    [2, 'two'],
    [3, 'three'],
    [4, 'four'],
    [5, 'five'],
    [6, 'six'],
    [7, 'seven'],
    [8, 'eight'],
    [9, 'nine'],
]
expected = [
    [1, 'one', 3, 'three'],
    [2, 'two', 4, 'four'],
    # page break
    [5, 'five', 7, 'seven'],
    [6, 'six', 8, 'eight'],
    # page break
    [9, 'nine'],
]
```

Just wondering if there's a quick way of doing this?

Comment: Could you check your testcase, and if it is right this way, explain how you get it? I would think of `1-3-5-7-9 - 2-4-6-8` and not `1-3 - 2-4 - 5-7 - 6-8 - 9` as a "columnisation" of a list

Comment: This makes more sense for 'columnise': `C=2; [[y for x in start[C*z:C*z+C] for y in x] for z in range(len(start)//C+1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments about this being a strange way to 'columnize'. However, here is a function that does what you described:

```
def columnize(A, interval=2):
    ans = []
    for i in range(0,len(A), interval*2):
        for j in range(min(interval, len(A)-i)):
            ans.append(A[i+j] + (A[i+j+interval] if i+j+interval < len(A) else []))
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? Columnizing squared matrix?

```
start = [
    [1, 'one'],
    [2, 'two'],
    [3, 'three'],
    [4, 'four'],
    [5, 'five'],
    [6, 'six'],
    [7, 'seven'],
    [8, 'eight'],
    [9, 'nine'],
]
expected = [
    [1, 'one', 3, 'three'],
    [2, 'two', 4, 'four'],
    # page break
    [5, 'five', 7, 'seven'],
    [6, 'six', 8, 'eight'],
    # page break
    [9, 'nine'],
]
a = 2
r = a*a
ans = []
for i in range(0, len(start), r):
    l_tmp = start[i:i+r]
    if l_tmp[::a]:
        ans.append([item for sublist in l_tmp[::a] for item in sublist])
    if l_tmp[1::a]:
        ans.append([item for sublist in l_tmp[1::a] for item in sublist])
    # You can easily add page break here
print(ans)
```